# Diagnosing cause of corrupt files on new system - motherboard, drive or other

Tags: windows-10, file-corruption, nvme

I have a new system build which contains two physical nvme drives on an asus prime x399-a mb. With a fresh Windows 10 install I see files being corrupted.

I first noticed this when several game launchers were failing and resetting downloads, but then also with windows media builder which failed and then built a corrupt ISO.

I also recently saw the behaviour when copying a ubuntu image from a usb drive to one of the nvme drives - when inspected with a binary diff, a single byte had changed. Both drives seem to exhibit this issue.

I have ran disk check against both drives and they report no issues. I have updated all drivers have run the windows memory diagnostic which reports all is fine.

I've run malware bytes and a virus scan and found nothing and I'm seeing no errors of note, and have tried reinstalling windows several times with no luck.

Any ideas what this might be or how I can get to the bottom of it would be much appreciated

**Update:**

The last installation quickly deteriorated to the point it wouldn't enter windows, just got BSOD: system thread exception not handled

I have reinstalled windows on an old ssd drive and the system is more or less stable but whilst repeatedly moving a file between the two nvme drives I got the following corruption after a few moves going from what was previously the boot drive to the secondary nvme:

```
C:\Windows\system32>fc /B F:\Images\ubuntu-18.04.3-desktop-amd64rm.iso E:\ubuntu-18.04.3-desktop-amd64rm.iso
Comparing files F:\IMAGES\ubuntu-18.04.3-desktop-amd64rm.iso and E:\UBUNTU-18.04.3-DESKTOP-AMD64RM.ISO
05980221: B3 F3
07AFF221: 3D 7D
1035B221: 82 C2
11174221: 8E CE
2FF8C221: 0E 4E
31847221: 0E 4E
```

how can i pin down what is failing

Comment: Proper downloads do not corrupt on any of my own Windows 10 machines (5 years now) or any client machine. Look in Windows Defender quarantine for signs of viruses. Update both wired and wireless drivers as well

Comment: Which byte has changed? Have you checked the SMART values of the disk?

Comment: thanks for the suggestions - I have updated bios and all drivers apart from the raid controller (which wont update because i installed windows on an nvme drive - but im not using raid *chicken/egg*) - I fired up crystaldiskinfo and it says health is good across the board. I'll do some more testing and report back as to whether the problem persists

Comment: with regards to which byte was changed, I couldnt tell you more than it was a single byte somewhere in the middle of the file  - I have replaced now and the subsequent operation worked so cant recompare to get more info

Comment: Most likely hardware, perhaps even the disk controller, meaning the motherboard. A useful article : [Best Free Hard Drive Health Monitoring and Diagnostic Programs](https://www.techsupportalert.com/best-free-disk-health-monitoring-utility.htm).